# How to display very large text in Rich Editable Text Input

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I am unable to display big text in Rich Editable text input control in flex 4. Below is the code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="500" height="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Scroller height="100%" width="100%">
    <s:Group height="100%" width="100%">

    <s:RichEditableText editable="false" text="75491302459 75491301083 75491311425 75491301095 75491300318 79004500202 09689827513 09689890273 09736156223 09689835913 09689829263 08539378773 04339607323 79004500205 08539244963 79004500204 79004500207 79004500208 09736155880 79405180133 09736337123 09736016920 79004500209 09736339363 09736337723 09736334300 04339674653 09736155680 09736156270 09736155783 09736062540 04339605870 09736339360 09736156600 09736320543 01223612441 01223612032 08539122223 02761654083 08539132283 01256957003 01476412543 02761685241 08539119513 79404362053 04598602070 04598602079 08539210793 04339600637 04339602221 04598624138 04598624108 04598624100 04598624103 04598624148 04598222222 04598624144 04339600671 04339606169 04339606520 04339607951 04339608142 04339609623 04339609671 04339605471 79004500222 79404367333 79404340363 08539144793 79004500223 08539173713 09736154463 04339607628 04339608284 04339608285 04339610096 08539210693 79004500225 79004500226 79404356453 79404356533 79404355483 04339601032 04339607682 04339607683 04339608575 04339608576 08539218513 04339602270 79404340103 79404343103 08539172473 09736871858 79404354513 79404368423 08539226243 04339612223 08539233013 79004500227 04598602518 04598602521 04598602529 04339605125 04339601788 75491300237 08539126143 75491300697 79404362103 04598624132 09689849593 08539342153 79404346873 02454303425 02454304708 02454305759 04339602945 04339609596 04339609744 04339682593 08539212503 09689836553 09736332510 09736334813 09736340723 09736874773 66706860263 66706899713 66706899753 66706899773 66706899793 67814901483 67814906653 67814931073 79404346383 04339602129 08539210823 04339601058 04339609621 04339608145 04339602148 04339651223 02454305755 79404346433 04339687030 09689848303 79004500206 04339603765 04339607051 04339609443 04339690313 04339694473 04339677923 04339662020 04339683343 04339691973 04339694393 04339660498 04339660237 04598602017 76218881272 75491300157 05393925653 08539141913 02761688731 09736886333 08539275723 07464559143 07464543283 07464559263 09736344573 02761688213 04598602085 04598602257 08539001784 08539178453 08539161083 01871374742 02761651223 08539246563 04598624116 04598608964 02761685244 09736153783 02761669653 01256969580 09736081363 04598624216 02761688430 09736874443 09736874673 09736879053 09736879583 09736879593 02761651373 70440002523 70440003123 70440003183 70440003203 70440003743 70440002703 70440002843 70440002903 04339609673 02848511541 09689601373 08539153723 08539159233 08539153003 09736879293 09736879783 08539153863 02761662283 09736014543 01476412143 09736344073 04598625701 04598625703 04598625702 09736015393 09736018233 09689812283 08539178043 09736877883 09736084593 02761687393 04339608607 04339608606 08539397443 08539348743 08539236633 09736341463 01256971599 02454302852 04339602152 09736156733 09736871623 02635921643 02635921633 09736016433 08539172013 09736330473 04598625704 04598625705 09736332433 09736875333 09736875343 01476412593 01476411933 09689897613 08539313393 09736156513 04598624163 70772955023 70772910116 09736340763 09736343493 02761661373 79404343093 79404343523 79404343493 08539309223 04598624212 01256959324 02454302939 09689847603 08539373073 00968983591 08539389473 09736014673 08539214153 09689849583 09736053823 09736053743 09736019493 08539212513 01256969983 01476414243 09736330553 02635913923 08539166893 09736331313 09736332443 08536518693 08536518843 09736877523 09736874453 09736845473 02454312130 09736341813 01476418793 01476423753 01476418783 01476413783 01476414793 01476418033 01476423743 01256944643 01476417453 01476417463 01476411983 01476419313 01476421503 01476417593 01476421563 01476423803 01476423903 01476420623 01476414863 01476412553 01476421683 08539238793 01476414873 01476419343 02761673033 02761677463 01256959335 09736045203 04339603415 02761661563 09736860163 09736860153 09736025143 09736879543 09736879553 97368601536 97368601635 03150401180 09736088581 09736041933 09736337223 01223273873 08539184363 09736065243 08539232493 02761665453 02761675863 09689897623 04598624210 02761677263 08536518453 01256957763 01256957563 09736061903 02761674093 09736880243 04339606814 08539186183 02761690110 09689812893 04598602530 00853003170 09736342303 70440005653 02635917243 04339621670 04598624211 09689867403 09736341263 01476423853 76218812720 01223614244 02454301469 02454304705 02454310674 02454312129 02454313000 02454312995 02454316035 02454316143 02454317638 02454320012 02454320022 02454320031 02454322206 02761690372 03242900577 08539151833 08539160543 08539164023 08539185343 08539189563 08539234823 08539275803 08539283853 08539284133 08539389413 09736050583 09736053820 09736055313 09736804013 09736837413 09736838743 09736860150 09736860180 09736860183 09736874430 09736874670 09736875633 09736877363 09736877393 09736877403 09736877413 09736877533 09736879103 09736879143 09736879243 09736879283 09736879673 09736879753 09736880173 09736880973 09736880983 09736880993 09736881883 09736881893 09736886233 09736886303 09736886483 09736886493 09736886503 09736886643 09736886653 09736886683 09736886353 09736887333 09736887553 09736889023 09736889443 09736889683 09736889883 09736889913 66706890213 67814908723 67814916803 79404354033 79404356253 79404363183 79404368293 79404368323 79405484213 79405485063 84188705022 84188705026 84188705028 84188705092 84188705116 84188705159 84188705191 09689824183 09736325833 09689817443 02454313318 08539220823 08539232993 08539233113 08539240503 08539313503 08539389533 09689610353 09689800763 09736053262 01223612988 01256959762 01223616239 79404310097 79404340353 79404362343 08539397433 08539276663 09736877383 08536518683 01256945863 04339608435 01223613350 01223613787 01256970355 01476414533 02454316125 02454319863 07464495983 07464540473 07464540493 07464543703 08536518673 08539224403 08539240963 08539247453 08539339853 08539365193 08539374243 79404345903 01223613093 01256959332 01476418433 02454312312 02454317538 03139811805 07464512293 07464553263 08536518623 08536519043 08539139253 08539149803 08539189553 08539224253 08539245933 08539284513 09689619963 09736837183 09736877443 09736877583 09736877893 70440007225 79404348833 08539232393 08539278783 09736877733 79404365033 09736871843 02635919933 04339603892 09689816083 02454311602 79404354153 79404363173 04339608077 79404357233 79404369273 79404354023 79404354853 04339605696 09736155883 02761681033 79404347153 79404347543 04339682653 79404345773 04339682433 04339621703 04339621693 08539129923 75491301083 75491311425 75491301095 75491300318 79004500202 09689827513 09689890273 09736156223 09689835913 09689829263 08539378773 04339607323 79004500205 08539244963 79004500204 79004500207 79004500208 09736155880 79405180133 09736337123 09736016920 79004500209 09736339363 09736337723 09736334300 04339674653 09736155680 09736156270 09736155783 09736062540 04339605870 09736339360 09736156600 09736320543 01223612441 01223612032 08539122223 02761654083 08539132283 01256957003 01476412543 02761685241 08539119513 79404362053 04598602070 04598602079 08539210793 04339600637 04339602221 04598624138 04598624108 04598624100 04598624103 04598624148 04598222222 04598624144 04339600671 04339606169 04339606520 04339607951 04339608142 04339609623 04339609671 04339605471 79004500222 79404367333 79404340363 08539144793 79004500223 08539173713 09736154463 04339607628 04339608284 04339608285 04339610096 08539210693 79004500225 79004500226 79404356453 79404356533 79404355483 04339601032 04339607682 04339607683 04339608575 04339608576 08539218513 04339602270 79404340103 79404343103 08539172473 09736871858 79404354513 79404368423 08539226243 04339612223 08539233013 79004500227 04598602518 04598602521 04598602529 04339605125 04339601788 75491300237 08539126143 75491300697 79404362103 04598624132 09689849593 08539342153 79404346873 02454303425 02454304708 02454305759 04339602945 04339609596 04339609744 04339682593 08539212503 09689836553 09736332510 09736334813 09736340723 09736874773 66706860263 66706899713 66706899753 66706899773 66706899793 67814901483 67814906653 67814931073 79404346383 04339602129 08539210823 04339601058 04339609621 04339608145 04339602148 04339651223 02454305755 79404346433 04339687030 09689848303 79004500206 04339603765 04339607051 04339609443 04339690313 04339694473 04339677923 04339662020 04339683343 04339691973 04339694393 04339660498 04339660237 04598602017 76218881272 75491300157 05393925653 08539141913 02761688731 09736886333 08539275723 07464559143 07464543283 07464559263 09736344573 02761688213 04598602085 04598602257 08539001784 08539178453 08539161083 01871374742 02761651223 08539246563 04598624116 04598608964 02761685244 09736153783 02761669653 01256969580 09736081363 04598624216 02761688430 09736874443 09736874673 09736879053 09736879583 09736879593 02761651373 70440002523 70440003123 70440003183 70440003203 70440003743 70440002703 70440002843 70440002903 04339609673 02848511541 09689601373 08539153723 08539159233 08539153003 09736879293 09736879783 08539153863 02761662283 09736014543 01476412143 09736344073 04598625701 04598625703 04598625702 09736015393 09736018233 09689812283 08539178043 09736877883 09736084593 02761687393 04339608607 04339608606 08539397443 08539348743 08539236633 09736341463 01256971599 02454302852 04339602152 09736156733 09736871623 02635921643 02635921633 09736016433 08539172013 09736330473 04598625704 04598625705 09736332433 09736875333 09736875343 01476412593 01476411933 09689897613 08539313393 09736156513 04598624163 70772955023 70772910116 09736340763 09736343493 02761661373 79404343093 79404343523 79404343493 08539309223 04598624212 01256959324 02454302939 09689847603 08539373073 00968983591 08539389473 09736014673 08539214153 09689849583 09736053823 09736053743 09736019493 08539212513 01256969983 01476414243 09736330553 02635913923 08539166893 09736331313 09736332443 08536518693 08536518843 09736877523 09736874453 09736845473 02454312130 09736341813 01476418793 01476423753 01476418783 01476413783 01476414793 01476418033 01476423743 01256944643 01476417453 01476417463 01476411983 01476419313 01476421503 01476417593 01476421563 01476423803 01476423903 01476420623 01476414863 01476412553 01476421683 08539238793 01476414873 01476419343 02761673033 02761677463 01256959335 09736045203 04339603415 02761661563 09736860163 09736860153 09736025143 09736879543 09736879553 97368601536 97368601635 03150401180 09736088581 09736041933 09736337223 01223273873 08539184363 09736065243 08539232493 02761665453 02761675863 09689897623 04598624210 02761677263 08536518453 01256957763 01256957563 09736061903 02761674093 09736880243 04339606814 08539186183 02761690110 09689812893 04598602530 00853003170 09736342303 70440005653 02635917243 04339621670 04598624211 09689867403 09736341263 01476423853 76218812720 01223614244 02454301469 02454304705 02454310674 02454312129 02454313000 02454312995 02454316035 02454316143 02454317638 02454320012 02454320022 02454320031 02454322206 02761690372 03242900577 08539151833 08539160543 08539164023 08539185343 08539189563 08539234823 08539275803 08539283853 08539284133 08539389413 09736050583 09736053820 09736055313 09736804013 09736837413 09736838743 09736860150 09736860180 09736860183 09736874430 09736874670 09736875633 09736877363 09736877393 09736877403 09736877413 09736877533 09736879103 09736879143 09736879243 09736879283 09736879673 09736879753 09736880173 09736880973 09736880983 09736880993 09736881883 09736881893 09736886233 09736886303 09736886483 09736886493 09736886503 09736886643 09736886653 09736886683 09736886353 09736887333 09736887553 09736889023 09736889443 09736889683 09736889883 09736889913 66706890213 67814908723 67814916803 79404354033 79404356253 79404363183 79404368293 79404368323 79405484213 79405485063 84188705022 84188705026 84188705028 84188705092 84188705116 84188705159 84188705191 09689824183 09736325833 09689817443 02454313318 08539220823 08539232993 08539233113 08539240503 08539313503 08539389533 09689610353 09689800763 09736053262 01223612988 01256959762 01223616239 79404310097 79404340353 79404362343 08539397433 08539276663 09736877383 08536518683 01256945863 04339608435 01223613350 01223613787 01256970355 01476414533 02454316125 02454319863 07464495983 07464540473 07464540493 07464543703 08536518673 08539224403 08539240963 08539247453 08539339853 08539365193 08539374243 79404345903 01223613093 01256959332 01476418433 02454312312 02454317538 03139811805 07464512293 07464553263 08536518623 08536519043 08539139253 08539149803 08539189553 08539224253 08539245933 08539284513 09689619963 09736837183 09736877443 09736877583 09736877893 70440007225 79404348833 08539232393 08539278783 09736877733 79404365033 09736871843 02635919933 04339603892 09689816083 02454311602 79404354153 79404363173 04339608077 79404357233 79404369273 79404354023 79404354853 04339605696 09736155883 02761681033 79404347153 79404347543 04339682653 79404345773 04339682433 04339621703 04339621693 08539129923 75491301083 75491311425 75491301095 75491300318 79004500202 09689827513 09689890273 09736156223 09689835913 09689829263 08539378773 04339607323 79004500205 08539244963 79004500204 79004500207 79004500208 09736155880 79405180133 09736337123 09736016920 79004500209 09736339363 09736337723 09736334300 04339674653 09736155680 09736156270 09736155783 09736062540 04339605870 09736339360 09736156600 09736320543 01223612441 01223612032 08539122223 02761654083 08539132283 01256957003 01476412543 02761685241 08539119513 79404362053 04598602070 04598602079 08539210793 04339600637 04339602221 04598624138 04598624108 04598624100 04598624103 04598624148 04598222222 04598624144 04339600671 04339606169 04339606520 04339607951 04339608142 04339609623 04339609671 04339605471 79004500222 79404367333 79404340363 08539144793 79004500223 08539173713 09736154463 04339607628 04339608284 04339608285 04339610096 08539210693 79004500225 79004500226 79404356453 79404356533 79404355483 04339601032 04339607682 04339607683 04339608575 04339608576 08539218513 04339602270 79404340103 79404343103 08539172473 09736871858 79404354513 79404368423 08539226243 04339612223 08539233013 79004500227 04598602518 04598602521 04598602529 04339605125 04339601788 75491300237 08539126143 75491300697 79404362103 04598624132 09689849593 08539342153 79404346873 02454303425 02454304708 02454305759 04339602945 04339609596 04339609744 04339682593 08539212503 09689836553 09736332510 09736334813 09736340723 09736874773 66706860263 66706899713 66706899753 66706899773 66706899793 67814901483 67814906653 67814931073 79404346383 04339602129 08539210823 04339601058 04339609621 04339608145 04339602148 04339651223 02454305755 79404346433 04339687030 09689848303 79004500206 04339603765 04339607051 04339609443 04339690313 04339694473 04339677923 04339662020 04339683343 04339691973 04339694393 04339660498 04339660237 04598602017 76218881272 75491300157 05393925653 08539141913 02761688731 09736886333 08539275723 07464559143 07464543283 07464559263 09736344573 02761688213 04598602085 04598602257 08539001784 08539178453 08539161083 01871374742 02761651223 08539246563 04598624116 04598608964 02761685244 09736153783 02761669653 01256969580 09736081363 04598624216 02761688430 09736874443 09736874673 09736879053 09736879583 09736879593 02761651373 70440002523 70440003123 70440003183 70440003203 70440003743 70440002703 70440002843 70440002903 04339609673 02848511541 09689601373 08539153723 08539159233 08539153003 09736879293 09736879783 08539153863 02761662283 09736014543 01476412143 09736344073 04598625701 04598625703 04598625702 09736015393 09736018233 09689812283 08539178043 09736877883 09736084593 02761687393 04339608607 04339608606 08539397443 08539348743 08539236633 09736341463 01256971599 02454302852 04339602152 09736156733 09736871623 02635921643 02635921633 09736016433 08539172013 09736330473 04598625704 04598625705 09736332433 09736875333 09736875343 01476412593 01476411933 09689897613 08539313393 09736156513 04598624163 70772955023 70772910116 09736340763 09736343493 02761661373 79404343093 79404343523 79404343493 08539309223 04598624212 01256959324 02454302939 09689847603 08539373073 00968983591 08539389473 09736014673 08539214153 09689849583 09736053823 09736053743 09736019493 08539212513 01256969983 01476414243 09736330553 02635913923 08539166893 09736331313 09736332443 08536518693 08536518843 09736877523 09736874453 09736845473 02454312130 09736341813 01476418793 01476423753 01476418783 01476413783 01476414793 01476418033 01476423743 01256944643 01476417453 01476417463 01476411983 01476419313 01476421503 01476417593 01476421563 01476423803 01476423903 01476420623 01476414863 01476412553 01476421683 08539238793 01476414873 01476419343 02761673033 02761677463 01256959335 09736045203 04339603415 02761661563 09736860163 09736860153 09736025143 09736879543 09736879553 97368601536 97368601635 03150401180 09736088581 09736041933 09736337223 01223273873 08539184363 09736065243 08539232493 02761665453 02761675863 09689897623 04598624210 02761677263 08536518453 01256957763 01256957563 09736061903 02761674093 09736880243 04339606814 08539186183 02761690110 09689812893 04598602530 00853003170 09736342303 70440005653 02635917243 04339621670 04598624211 09689867403 09736341263 01476423853 76218812720 01223614244 02454301469 02454304705 02454310674 02454312129 02454313000 02454312995 02454316035 02454316143 02454317638 02454320012 02454320022 02454320031 02454322206 02761690372 03242900577 08539151833 08539160543 08539164023 08539185343 08539189563 08539234823 08539275803 08539283853 08539284133 08539389413 09736050583 09736053820 09736055313 09736804013 09736837413 09736838743 09736860150 09736860180 09736860183 09736874430 09736874670 09736875633 09736877363 09736877393 09736877403 09736877413 09736877533 09736879103 09736879143 09736879243 09736879283 09736879673 09736879753 09736880173 09736880973 09736880983 09736880993 09736881883 09736881893 09736886233 09736886303 09736886483 09736886493 09736886503 09736886643 09736886653 09736886683 09736886353 09736887333 09736887553 09736889023 09736889443 09736889683 09736889883 09736889913 66706890213 67814908723 67814916803 79404354033 79404356253 79404363183 79404368293 79404368323 79405484213 79405485063 84188705022 84188705026 84188705028 84188705092 84188705116 84188705159 84188705191 09689824183 09736325833 09689817443 02454313318 08539220823 08539232993 08539233113 08539240503 08539313503 08539389533 09689610353 09689800763 09736053262 01223612988 01256959762 01223616239 79404310097 79404340353 79404362343 08539397433 08539276663 09736877383 08536518683 01256945863 04339608435 01223613350 01223613787 01256970355 01476414533 02454316125 02454319863 07464495983 07464540473 07464540493 07464543703 08536518673 08539224403 08539240963 08539247453 08539339853 08539365193 08539374243 79404345903 01223613093 01256959332 01476418433 02454312312 02454317538 03139811805 07464512293 07464553263 08536518623 08536519043 08539139253 08539149803 08539189553 08539224253 08539245933 08539284513 09689619963 09736837183 09736877443 09736877583 09736877893 70440007225 79404348833 08539232393 08539278783 09736877733 79404365033 09736871843 02635919933 04339603892 09689816083 02454311602 79404354153 79404363173 04339608077 79404357233 79404369273 79404354023 79404354853 04339605696 09736155883 02761681033 79404347153 79404347543 04339682653 79404345773 04339682433 04339621703 04339621693 08539129923 75491301083 75491311425 75491301095 75491300318 79004500202 09689827513 09689890273 09736156223 09689835913 09689829263 08539378773 04339607323 79004500205 08539244963 79004500204 79004500207 79004500208 09736155880 79405180133 09736337123 09736016920 79004500209 09736339363 09736337723 09736334300 04339674653 09736155680 09736156270 09736155783 09736062540 04339605870 09736339360 09736156600 09736320543 01223612441 01223612032 08539122223 02761654083 08539132283 01256957003 01476412543 02761685241 08539119513 79404362053 04598602070 04598602079 08539210793 04339600637 04339602221 04598624138 04598624108 04598624100 04598624103 04598624148 04598222222 04598624144 04339600671 04339606169 04339606520 04339607951 04339608142 04339609623 04339609671 04339605471 79004500222 79404367333 79404340363 08539144793 79004500223 08539173713 09736154463 04339607628 04339608284 04339608285 04339610096 08539210693 79004500225 79004500226 79404356453 79404356533 79404355483 04339601032 04339607682 04339607683 04339608575 04339608576 08539218513 04339602270 79404340103 79404343103 08539172473 09736871858 79404354513 79404368423 08539226243 04339612223 08539233013 79004500227 04598602518 04598602521 04598602529 04339605125 04339601788 75491300237 08539126143 75491300697 79404362103 04598624132 09689849593 08539342153 79404346873 02454303425 02454304708 02454305759 04339602945 04339609596 04339609744 04339682593 08539212503 09689836553 09736332510 09736334813 09736340723 09736874773 66706860263 66706899713 66706899753 66706899773 66706899793 67814901483 67814906653 67814931073 79404346383 04339602129 08539210823 04339601058 04339609621 04339608145 04339602148 04339651223 02454305755 79404346433 04339687030 09689848303 79004500206 04339603765 04339607051 04339609443 04339690313 04339694473 04339677923 04339662020 04339683343 04339691973 04339694393 04339660498 04339660237 04598602017 76218881272 75491300157 05393925653 08539141913 02761688731 09736886333 08539275723 07464559143 07464543283 07464559263 09736344573 02761688213 04598602085 04598602257 08539001784 08539178453 08539161083 01871374742 02761651223 08539246563 04598624116 04598608964 02761685244 09736153783 02761669653 01256969580 09736081363 04598624216 02761688430 09736874443 09736874673 09736879053 09736879583 09736879593 02761651373 70440002523 70440003123 70440003183 70440003203 70440003743 70440002703 70440002843 70440002903 04339609673 02848511541 09689601373 08539153723 08539159233 08539153003 09736879293 09736879783 08539153863 02761662283 09736014543 01476412143 09736344073 04598625701 04598625703 04598625702 09736015393 09736018233 09689812283 08539178043 09736877883 09736084593 02761687393 04339608607 04339608606 08539397443 08539348743 08539236633 09736341463 01256971599 02454302852 04339602152 09736156733 09736871623 02635921643 02635921633 09736016433 08539172013 09736330473 04598625704 04598625705 09736332433 09736875333 09736875343 01476412593 01476411933 09689897613 08539313393 09736156513 04598624163 70772955023 70772910116 09736340763 09736343493 02761661373 79404343093 79404343523 79404343493 08539309223 04598624212 01256959324 02454302939 09689847603 08539373073 00968983591 08539389473 09736014673 08539214153 09689849583 09736053823 09736053743 09736019493 08539212513 01256969983 01476414243 09736330553 02635913923 08539166893 09736331313 09736332443 08536518693 08536518843 09736877523 09736874453 09736845473 02454312130 09736341813 01476418793 01476423753 01476418783 01476413783 01476414793 01476418033 01476423743 01256944643 01476417453 01476417463 01476411983 01476419313 01476421503 01476417593 01476421563 01476423803 01476423903 01476420623 01476414863 01476412553 01476421683 08539238793 01476414873 01476419343 02761673033 02761677463 01256959335 09736045203 04339603415 02761661563 09736860163 09736860153 09736025143 09736879543 09736879553 97368601536 97368601635 03150401180 09736088581 09736041933 09736337223 01223273873 08539184363 09736065243 08539232493 02761665453 02761675863 09689897623 04598624210 02761677263 08536518453 01256957763 01256957563 09736061903 02761674093 09736880243 04339606814 08539186183 02761690110 09689812893 04598602530 00853003170 09736342303 70440005653 02635917243 04339621670 04598624211 09689867403 09736341263 01476423853 76218812720 01223614244 02454301469 02454304705 02454310674 02454312129 02454313000 02454312995 02454316035 02454316143 02454317638 02454320012 02454320022 02454320031 02454322206 02761690372 03242900577 08539151833 08539160543 08539164023 08539185343 08539189563 08539234823 08539275803 08539283853 08539284133 08539389413 09736050583 09736053820 09736055313 09736804013 09736837413 09736838743 09736860150 09736860180 09736860183 09736874430 09736874670 09736875633 09736877363 09736877393 09736877403 09736877413 09736877533 09736879103 09736879143 09736879243 09736879283 09736879673 09736879753 09736880173 09736880973 09736880983 09736880993 09736881883 09736881893 09736886233 09736886303 09736886483 09736886493 09736886503 09736886643 09736886653 09736886683 09736886353 09736887333 09736887553 09736889023 09736889443 09736889683 09736889883 09736889913 66706890213 67814908723 67814916803 79404354033 79404356253 79404363183 79404368293 79404368323 79405484213 79405485063 84188705022 84188705026 84188705028 84188705092 84188705116 84188705159 84188705191 09689824183 09736325833 09689817443 02454313318 08539220823 08539232993 08539233113 08539240503 08539313503 08539389533 09689610353 09689800763 09736053262 01223612988 01256959762 01223616239 79404310097 79404340353 79404362343 08539397433 08539276663 09736877383 08536518683 01256945863 04339608435 01223613350 01223613787 01256970355 01476414533 02454316125 02454319863 07464495983 07464540473" top="50" bottom="50"/>
    </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>

</s:Application>
```

Can any one please tell me how to display big text in Rich editable text input control

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the problem is that it doesn't wrap. You can add height, width and multiline properties to force it to wrap.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">
    <s:Scroller height="100%" width="100%"  >
        <s:Group height="100%" width="100%">
            <s:RichEditableText height="100%" width="100%"  multiline="true" editable="false" text="..." top="50" bottom="50"/>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks for solution nFreeze it is visible now in multiple lines but i need small modification.That is the text should be visible in one line upto some 20 characters after that i should get "......" concat format.I have given tooltip to display the original text. can you please help me.

Comment: Could you add a mock-up of the result you are looking for to your question? I don't fully understand.